# Spring Boot devtools IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, groovy, gradle, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.0.M5 and I am trying to take advantage of devtools. This allows you to make changes to your application while in development and boot will reload your application. I have seen this demo work in STS using Java and Maven.

I am trying to use Groovy & Gradle in IntelliJ 14.1 and I am having some issues. First here is my Gradle Build dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") 
}
```

I created a controller with a mapping for "/"

```
package demo

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        "Hello, SpringOne 2GX!"
    }

}
```

I am able to run the application and visit http://localhost:8080 and see the string print to the screen. If I make a change to the file nothing happens because IntelliJ does not compile on change. If you go to Build > Make Project though I can see Spring Boot in the console reload. So this seems to be working but if I go back to the root URL I get the following error which is basically what you would see if you had no controllers in place.

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Sep 17 10:43:25 EDT 2015 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

Anyone know why the reload is not working correctly for me?

Comment: does it work if you run a `gradle classes` instead?

Comment: @cfrick no same issue. Spring Boot reloads and I get the white label error.

Comment: and you run this with `gradle bootRun`?

Comment: what's the stacktrace on the server?

Comment: @cfrick bootRun or Run > Run Demo Application.

Comment: I also upgraded to IntelliJ 15 EPA to see if that was the issue and no change.

Comment: Are you able to see the original page? I.e. is it not reloading, or is compiling breaking your built? instead of going to `Build > Make Project`, can you try pressing `CTRL + Shift + F9`?

Comment: And one last idea: take a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3315)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue recently. The problem is in the way devtools intercepts changes. By default it waits for 1 second for compiling to be finished. If class doesn't exist on classpath after that time then devtools consider class was deleted and restart application without it.

Most times it takes 3 second in average for groovy to finish compilation  process on my machine. Therefore class getting removed while restart.

The solution for this issue is to set **spring.devtools.restart.pollInterval** property in **application.properties** file to value greater than 1000 (for me 4000 works fine).

Answer (score 0):

It's will be ok if you specify the exact package to scan. Such as:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.lsj.web")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class PlatformApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(PlatformApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```