# Spring Boot - Rest Controller fails after hot swap

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.1 with devtools and run it within IntelliJ 14.1
All works nicely except the hot swap. My changes to the controllers are hot swapped and I can see the app being re-loaded. However, it results in an error and the controller become unavailable (404).
After I restart the app, all works fine again.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance for your help
Edward

Comment: can you post the stacktrace you get?

Comment: [Possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019938/springboot-devtools-restcontroller-not-always-mapped-when-rebuild-project/39084997#39084997)

Comment: Thank you Morfic, the link you provided helps. I will update the question for the gain of others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question, the problem is resolved by adding the following to the application.properties

```
## Amount of time (in milliseconds) to wait between polling for classpath changes.
spring.devtools.restart.poll-interval=3000

# Amount of quiet time (in milliseconds) required without any classpath changes before a restart is triggered.
spring.devtools.restart.quiet-period=2999
```